# Android takes png files from wrong folder

Tags: android, android-resources, android-screen-support

In my app there are folders drawable-mdpi (for phones) and drawable-sw600dp-mdpi (for tablets). When i launch application tablet takes images from folder drawable-mdpi. But i think it's wrong behavior.

My device is Acer-A500 (1280x800 mdpi). How does android choose png?

Comment: You can specify the available screen width and/or height: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: how? i cannot type sw800px -> error

Comment: Of course... it's **dp**, not **px**. Please, re-read the docs. Paying attention, this time.

Comment: In particular, **this** section: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#ConfigurationExamples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acer-A500 was launched with Android 3.0 the identifier `sw600dp` didn't exist back then, so the tablet doesn't know it exists.

Newer devices shouldn't have problem finding it. You can check  by using an emulator.

Comment: What android versions support identifier like sw600dp? From api-level 14?